# CSS does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm having a problem with the CSS in IE, on this page:

http://www.carby.cz/index1.php

It works in every browser except IE. I am helpless; I've tried everything I found on the forums and none of the styles in the page are showing up in IE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Describe the problem, add the relevant HTML and CSS, explain what you have tried. I think SO should have fill in the blank questions for first time posters.

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about. I see that you are using CSS3 and of course IE8 and less don't support CSS3.

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 3):

Your website mostly works in IE9 if you remove this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

That's telling IE to display the page in IE7 mode. Guess what? IE7 sucks.

For example, this won't work in IE7:

```css
.bg1 {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

You could use a semi-transparent `.png` as a fallback, which would work in IE7. Or, you could use `background-color: #fff; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);`, which will only use `rgba()` in browsers that support it.

Comment: thx the semitransparrent PNG seems to be good idea

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept my answer if it answered your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 and below don't support much CSS3.

You can add support for [certain things](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) if you integrate [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).